# React Hook Forms How to pass the errors as a props using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hook-form

I'm defining a useForm.

`const { handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm<{email: string}>();`

Now I'm creating a seperate component that will the input and I'm going to pass the `useForm` props i created above.

This how that Components look like.

```
type Props<T> = {
  name: FieldName<T>;
  control: Control<T>;
  errors: FieldErrors<T>;
};

const ControlTextInput = <T extends {}>({
  name,
  control,
  errors,
}: Props<T>) => {
  return (
   
    <Controller
    name={name}
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required:'this is required',
    }}
    render={({ onChange }) => (
        <>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                onChange(text);
                }}
            />
            {/* Show my error here */}
            {errors.email && (
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>
                    {errors.email?.message}
                </Text>
            )}
      </>
    )}
  />
  );
};
```

I want to use the component like this.

```
   <ControlTextInput<AnyObject>
                    name="email"
                    errors={errors}
                    control={control}
                  />
```

I get this error when i hover over the `errors.email`
[image]

Comment: errors property wont have an email object because its a genetic. after its being passed

Comment: Hi @Millenial2020, it would be great if you can post your code on Codesandbox and then share the link. Also, remove the stuff which is not relevant to the question. If you don't need rules, remove it. If you don't need that TextInput remove it, etc etc.

Comment: @Millenial2020 did you get any solution? stuck with same propblem.. When errors object passed to child like <Child errors={errors}> change detection is not working for nested objects...

Comment: Yeah I did. I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

React Hook Form exposes type `UseControllerProps` which accepts generic type T which infers your input value types or in other words the `FieldValues` type. Initially you define `FieldValues` type by passing type about your fields to `useForm` hook (see `MyInputTypes` below).

```
interface MyInputTypes {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<MyInputTypes>();
```

This means you can create interface which extends `UseControllerProps` and has your generic T `interface Props<T> extends UseControllerProps<T> {}`. Type `UseControllerProps` already includes type definitions for `name` and `control` and therefore you will not need to define them separately in your interface (unless you want to or there is a particular requirement / reason to do so). Regarding `errors` appropriate solution Imo (as you require only error about single field) would be to pass that particular error directly which has type `FieldError | undefined`. The result looks like below code.

```
interface Props<T> extends UseControllerProps<T> {
  error: FieldError | undefined
}
```

Then you can simply use your ControlTextInput as below.

```
<ControlTextInput name="email" error={errors.email} />
```

In the Component (which uses ControlTextInput) your generic T must extend `FieldValues` as eventually, it is this type which infers types about the fields.

As an example ControlTextInput

```
import React from 'react';
import { Controller, FieldError, FieldValues, UseControllerProps } from 'react-hook-form';

interface Props<T> extends UseControllerProps<T> {
  error: FieldError | undefined;
}

const ControlTextInput = <T extends FieldValues>({ name, control, error }: Props<T>) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={{
        required: 'This is required',
      }}
      render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
        <>
          <input
            onChange={(text) => {
              onChange(text);
            }}
          />
          {error && <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error?.message}</span>}
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default ControlTextInput;
```

As an example Component which uses ControlTextInput

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import ControlTextInput from './ControlTextInput';

interface InputTypes {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const Foo: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const {
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<InputTypes>();
  return <ControlTextInput name='email' error={errors.email} />;
};

export default Foo;
```

Here are screenshots with ready code which mimics more or less your approach and solution (same as code above as new to StackOverflow).

[ControlTextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNAUb.png)

[Component which uses ControlTextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OgFm.png)

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks - about time to contribute something back.

Comment: Do you know why I'm getting this error. TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'r.control')

Comment: @Millenial2020 I have an idea which relates to changed react-hook-form version which now requires to destructure "control" from useForm() (as per https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/control). Cannot remember the version I used at the time of writing of the original response so it's likely that internals have changed in such fast evolving library

Comment: Great answer, thank you!  I was able to fix up my subcomponents with proper types.  I had to declare my props interface with `<T extends FieldValues>` in order to get it to work, like this:  `interface Props<T extends FieldValues> extends UseControllerProps<T> {`, but otherwise your answer was clear and well-explained.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you example how to type props for passing `errors` or `register` method to child component (ChakraUI based):

```
interface Props<T extends FieldValues> extends UseControllerProps<T> {
    errors: FieldErrors<IFormData>;
    register: UseFormRegister<IFormData>;
}

export const Form = <T extends FieldValues>({
    register,
    errors,
}: Props<T>) => {
```

Form content:

```
<FormControl isInvalid={errors?.name? true : false}>
    <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        {...register('name', {
            required: 'This field is required',
        })}
    />
    {errors?.modelName && (
        <FormErrorMessage>
            {errors?.name?.message}
        </FormErrorMessage>
    )}
</FormControl>
```

Parent component:

```
export interface IFormData {
    name: string;
}
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
} = useForm<IFormData>({
    mode: 'onChange',
});

<form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
            <Form
                register={register}
                errors={errors}
                name={''}
            />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I found a solution is to use error type any
  `errors?: any;`

Use the lodash get function
 `const errName = get(errors, name);`

Then i can get the error has follow.

`{errName && <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>{errName.message}</Text>}`

Comment: This would lose any type safety. For example, calling errName.message.toUpperCase() would result in a runtime error.